# Are you considered ally of yourself using battleplan?

Tags: iron-kingdoms

Reading the battleplan abilites in the Core Book, I was wondering if you are considered ally of yourself and the guide says nothing about it. 
So, can you be considered ally of yourself?

Comment: Is there a specific battleplan ability that you're thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

**This depends on the Battleplan being used, and is in the wording of the exact battle plan.**

For example "GO TO GROUND" states

> . . .each friendly character who follows the
>   character's orders gains cover, does not suffer blast damage,
>   and does not block LOS until he moves, is placed, or is engaged.

Whereas "RECONNAISSANCE" specifies

> . . .the character and each friendly
>   character who starts his activation in his command range
>   gains the Pathfinder ability.

This means that if the character shouting the plan is not specifically mentioned, they are not included based on this precedent.

Comment: Would the character that issued the order not follow their own order? That seems... strange to state that way.